# How to access prototype property from within javascript class?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am knew to `javascript`, please excuse my rather basic question. 
How can I use a property from within my class, as in the sample code below?

```
function MyClass() {
  // nothing special
}

MyClass.prototype.myProperty = {
  key1: 'some value 1',
  key2: 'some value 2',
};

My Class.prototype.myFunction = function myFunction() {
  // I need to retrieve the first value of myProperty
  const x = myProperty[Object.keys(myProperty)[0]] + 10; // won't work
  return x;
};

module.exports = MyClass;
```

Using `this.myProperty` throws the error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.`:

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function myFunction() {
  const x = this.myProperty[Object.keys(this.myProperty)[0]] + 10;
  // -------^^^^^-----------------------^^^^^
  return x;
};
```

That will get the property from the object. If the object doesn't have its own copy of the property, it will get it from the object's prototype.

Or if you want to get it from the prototype every time, be explicit:

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function myFunction() {
  const p = MyClass.prototype.myProperty;
  const x = p[Object.keys(p)[0]] + 10;
  return x;
};
```

---

Side note: `const` is a new thing, as of ES2015. If you're using ES2015 (and it looks like you're using NodeJS, which means you can if you're using v6 or later), you can write your class more simply using `class` notation:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    // nothing special
  }
  myFunction() {
    const x = this.myProperty[Object.keys(this.myProperty)[0]] + 10;
    return x;
  }
}
MyClass.prototype.myProperty = {
  key1: 'some value 1',
  key2: 'some value 2',
};

module.exports = MyClass;
```

Note that if you want `myProperty` to be on the prototype, you do still need to assign it the "clunky" way. But you may want to create that property in the constructor instead.

---

Side note 2: Unless you change `myProperty` later, I strongly recommend using `this.myProperty.key1` or `this.myProperty.key2` and not using `this.myProperty[Object.keys(this.myProperty)[0]]`, which is hard to read, chaotic (undefined behavior, the order of the keys returned by `Object.keys` is not specified, not even in ES2015), and extra work.

Comment: Sorry I somehow invalidated the examples in your answer by updating my question! But it seems that `this.myProperty` is `undefined`. I guess because I never `new`ed the class???

Comment: @Yalda: Show how you're using it.

Comment: I think I'm closer to find out what the problem is. Actually, I used the same property in `myFunction` as well as another property. It seems that the error comes from the latter instead. That's a totally different question, so I will accept your answer for the current question :)